# Deploying Rails/Passenger via nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I'm having a hard time figuring out where I'm going wrong in trying to deploy a Rails app via nginx.  Rails is accessible via site.com:3000 (after starting it with `rails server`), and site.com:80 displays the standard nginx "working, but further configuration required" page.  I've spent a few hours trawling [the documentation](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_deploying_to_a_virtual_host_8217_s_root_2) trying to figure our how to get my Rails app accessible at :80 rather than :3000, but to no avail.

I think it's most likely that I'm misunderstanding how nginx, Passenger, and Rails work together, and have therefore configured my `nginx.conf` incorrectly (one page I found implied that I shouldn't both be using nginx and running `rails server`).  Any and all help is hugely appreciated.

Possibly relevant version numbers:

- Rails 4.1.4
- Ruby 2.1.2p95
- CentOS 6.5
- nginx 1.6.0
- nginx.conf partial: http://pastebin.com/A3JD09pr

Comment: Could you help with the steps you took deploy ?

Comment: The steps were the normal one through a tutorial I found online.  I'll add an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm new at this, so it turned out that a couple things were up:

- I needed to put `export rvmsudo_secure_path=1` in my .bashrc instead of just running it once, following up with `source ~/.bashrc` in the terminal.  This allowed me to run "rvmsudo" commands to start on port 80 rather than the default 3000.
- I had both nginx and Rails competing for port 80, so I had to stop nginx's static page server to allow that.  Simple as `nginx stop`.